# why does tikz connect my nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
```

and my code looks like this

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.16\textwidth] at (-0.34\textwidth,0) {Applet};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.16\textwidth] at (-0.17\textwidth,0) {Applet};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.16\textwidth] at (0,0) {Applet};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.5\textwidth] at (-0.17\textwidth,-0.7) {Java Card Operating System};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.3\textwidth] at (0.27\textwidth,-0.35) { Native \\ Application \vspace{8pt}};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.84\textwidth] at (0,-1.44) {\gls{ic} Platform};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Architecture of a \gls{smartcard}}
\label{figure:smartcardarchitecture}
\end{figure}
```

when I compile it the resulting picture is [image]

how do I get rid of the lines between the Applet boxes?

I would also be happy about some guidance on how to align the hight of the boxes properly - but not too complicated ;-).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: The boxes for the nodes are overlapping since they are too close together.

Comment: Hi, theoretically they should not be overlapping but I moved them by half a percent and that solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: @Karin Why shouldn't they theoretically be overlapping? You didn't take into account the `inner sep` for the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The `Applet`'s are too close each other and overlap. Please compare a modified example. I am not sure what your `\gls` means...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
and my code looks like this

\def\gls{\MakeUppercase}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,color=red,align=center,text width=0.16\textwidth] at (-0.34\textwidth,0) {Applet};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.16\textwidth] at (-0.17\textwidth,0) {Applet};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.16\textwidth] at (0,0) {Applet};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.5\textwidth] at (-0.17\textwidth,-0.7) {Java Card Operating System};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.3\textwidth] at (0.27\textwidth,-0.35) { Native \\ Application \vspace{8pt}};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=0.84\textwidth] at (0,-1.44) {\gls{ic}
 Platform};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Architecture of a \gls{smartcard}}
\label{figure:smartcardarchitecture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]